# Fork() call produces nothing, print statements not executed after Fork() call

Tags: c++, operating-system, fork

Here is my code

```
int main(){

printf("Start of process\n");
pid_t pid = 0;
int stat;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        printf("child isn't created\n");
    }
    exit(1);


    if (pid == 0)
    {

        if (i == 0)
        {
            char *argv1[2] = {"./summation.exe", NULL};
            execv("./summation.exe", argv1);
            printf("Summation process complete\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        // child2
        else
        {
            char *argv2[2] = {"./factorial.exe", NULL};
            execv("./factorial.exe", argv2);
            printf("Factorial process complete\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    // parent case
    else
    {
        // pid_t variable to store process id
        pid_t status = waitpid(pid, &stat, 0);

        if (status > 0)
        {
            printf("Child is terminated\n");
        }
```

My output is : "Start of process"

Why are none of the print statements after fork executed?
I use g++ to compile the code, and upon running ./filename.exe
the only output is the first print statement.

Comment: You call `exit(1);`. Why do you expect execution after it?

Comment: No headers. Code ends abruptly. And something about that `exit` just doesn't feel right.

Comment: Please remove the `c++` tag and add a `c` tag. There is absolutely nothing C++-related here.

Comment: Note that there are only three portable values for the argument to `exit`: `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE`, and 0 (which is equivalent to `EXIT_SUCCESS`). `exit(1)` will exit, but the value returned by the application is not guaranteed to mean anything.

Answer (score 2):

You are exiting directly after forking:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        printf("child isn't created\n");
    }
    exit(1); // <- Exits even if the child process is created.

    // ...
```

What you want to do is exit only when it fails to create the child process:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        printf("child isn't created\n");
        exit(1)
    }

    // ...
```